# iOS 10.1 : Push not working

Tags: push-notification, swift3, ios10

I have updated my devices to iOS 10.1 and somehow the push notification has stopped working. I still have a device on iOS 10.0.2 and I still receive notifications and silent push on this one.

I am working with xCode 8 and swift 3. I have implemented the required iOS 10 methods for swift and cannot really figure out what has changed with this update. Could not find any push related changes here too: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1893?locale=ja_JP&viewlocale=en_US.

Is there some other documentation/release notes maybe that I am missing here ? Anyone else facing the same issue ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is happening to me as well, did you find the solution? Also I noticed that in a device with iOS 9.3 push are working ok but after creating the entitlements file they stopped working. So I had to delete the file name from build settings -> Code signing entitlements and its working again.

Comment: @RafaelJimeno I still do not know what went wrong. But the push works now with 10.1.1. I guess apple fixed something with this version, though nothing as such is mentioned in release notes.